# restarting bitcoin tesnet docker container, error flag '-ti'

Tags: docker, bitcoin

I'm trying to restart a [docker container](https://github.com/c0achmcguirk/bitcoin-dev-box) so instead of using the command

```
docker run -ti --name btcdev -P -p 49020:19000 poliver/bitcoin-dev-box
```

but because `run` creates a new container- and it's already been created- I need to just reconnect to one that already working. So I'm using the command:

```
docker start -ti --name btcdev -P -p 49020:19000 poliver/bitcoin-dev-box
```

**but** I'm getting the **error**:

```
flag provided but not defined: -ti
```

so then, my question is, what does '-ti' mean?

can I just drop it?  as in- not use that?

I've been looking in the docker documentation but I've not been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker ps -a' shows you the containers, and importantly, their hashes.

next user `docker start HASH` to wake it up

then use `docker attach HASH` to connect, where HASH is the hash of the container